# Debugger causes internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I can no longer place `debugger` in my controller methods. I test API calls with Chrome's Postman. Methods all work but if I include `debugger` in a method (irrespective which method and irrespective the position I place `debugger` in the method) and call upon the method using Postman, I get an error. It never was a problem before. Could anyone please help find the cause?

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1335ms (ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)

SystemExit (exit):
  app/controllers/api/v1/organizations_controller.rb:35:in `update'

  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (190.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (51.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (321.7ms)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there must have been some kind of data corruption in the database. After dropping and rebuilding the database, the problem was gone. Still, it remains strange that the problem was only there when `debugger` was added to the method.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after using command "exit" inside byebug.

It worked properly after restarting my rails server.

Comment: The same occurred with me, so when restarting rails server the issue goes away.